# Android - Cube Out Transformer Not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, transform

I am using this [Library](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers) in order to create a transform effect on a pager. All the classes working good except for the `Cube Out` and `Cube In` transform. They appear white while scrolling.

I have also created a custom animation but it still not animate the pager.

What could be the problem here? and why only `setRotationY` is not working properly?

```
public class CubePageTrasformer extends BaseTransformer {

    @Override
    protected void onTransform(View view, float position) {




        final float height = view.getHeight();
        final float width = view.getWidth();

        view.setPivotX(position < 0f ? width : 0f);
        view.setPivotY(height * 0.5f);
        float rotation = (90f * position);
        view.setRotationY(rotation);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: It works fine on my Samsung 6.0 and not working on Huawei 7.0

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am running into the exact same issue with the same library! I found that disabling hardware acceleration in the Manifest resolves this issue. But I need hardware acceleration in my project

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as you and I found that the following change fixed the issue on all devices:

```
viewPager.clipChildren = false
```